Issue getting Magento Integration Request, Access Token through REST APIs
I'm trying to get the request token and access token in a Magento Integration using HttpClient in C#.
First I created a REST service (callback url) to capture the consumer key and consumer secret that is sent from a Magento Integration. Next I created an integration in Magento and set the above service as the callback url and an identity url (an auth server url).
Next I authorized the integration where the consumer secret and consumer key are sent to the callback as expected. I'm stuck on getting the request key and from that getting an access token so that I could use it to make REST API calls to get products and orders and such.
I followed the Magento Documentation and Adobe Commerce documentation but I cannot get the necessary key values. Are there any implementation examples that I could follow on this? any help or idea on this would be really helpful, thanks.
